# Mock Services Json

Tags: json, mocking

What is the simplest way to make mock json services?
Is there any program for that like there is for soap?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently wrote a library specifically for this purpose! It's called [Interfake](https://github.com/basicallydan/interfake).

You can write it in JavaScript, but you can also just create a JSON file and run interfake against it. All the instructions are in the readme :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try soapui

[Howto create a mock service to serve static json](http://partaker.soapui.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3830)